# How to make PathIcon stretch in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to use `PathIcon` just as same size with the text, like `NavigationItem`. I tried to use `<Image>` to implement it like this.

[image](https://i.loli.net/2020/11/29/D4oRHuNTIhvax3q.png)

but I want to use icon because it can auto change color in dark or white mode.

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Rectangle Width="20" Fill="BlanchedAlmond"/>
    <PathIcon Data="{StaticResource PowerPlantIcon}"/>
    <Rectangle Width="20" Fill="BlanchedAlmond"/>
    <PathIcon Data="{StaticResource PowerPlantIcon}" Height="20"/>
    <TextBlock Text="This is a Text" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And I get this:

[image](https://i.loli.net/2020/11/29/5W2hPMT1NkXrq9B.png)

Here is my custom `PathIcon` defined in App.xmal

```xml
<x:String x:Key="PowerPlantIcon">
   M43,50H36.12V46.24h5.27l4.85-4.85V8.55L41.38,3.76H36.12V0H43l7,7V43ZM13.87,50H7L0,43V7L7,0h6.88V3.76H8.55L3.76,8.55V41.38l4.79,4.79h5.33Zm4.7-7.06L32.46,23.59l-7-.58L31.35,8.7H20.29L17.56,25.53l4.44.55Z
</x:String>
```

I find the icon size has been auto set to 50x50 and cannot be changed through setting width or height.

After search everything I can find, did not find the solution to make `PathIcon` stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust the size of a `PathIcon` by putting the `PathIcon` into a [ViewBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox?view=winrt-19041). You could bind the `Width` property and `Height` property of the `ViewBox` control to the `TextBlock` control to implement the stretch effect.

Please check the following code as a reference:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Rectangle Width="20" Fill="BlanchedAlmond"/>
    <PathIcon Data="{StaticResource PowerPlantIcon}"/>
    <Rectangle Width="20" Fill="BlanchedAlmond"/>
    
    <Viewbox Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,ElementName=textBlock}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,ElementName=textBlock}">
        <PathIcon Data="{StaticResource PowerPlantIcon}"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="This is a Text" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```